# How to filter through date in django-views?(Doesn't show the expired one)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

models.py

```
class Dibbs_Fields(models.Model):
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    nsn = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    nomenclature = models.TextField()
    technical_documents = models.TextField()
    return_by = models.DateField()
```

How to filter this class in django views according to the date `return_by` ? I don't want to show the data that is expired i.e. if the `return_by` date is earlier than today's date, then it should not show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
from datetime import date

def func(request):
   today = date.today()
   data = Dibbs_Fields.objects.filter(
               return_by__lt=today)
```

The code simply returns data are earlier than today's date.

**EDIT**

```
return_by__lt # less than
return_by__gt # greater than
return_by__gte # greater than or equal to
return_by__lte # less than or equal to
```

Comment: I want data that are not earlier than today's date.

Comment: Then you can change `lt` to `gt`.